# C++ get current date

Tags: c++, date, get

I want to get current time day/month/year hour:minute:second
C++ seems to be pretty disgusting (well, it is itself) when it comes to such an easy problem.

I've searched internet all over and all I can get are deprecated c functions or functions being thread unsafe. I've found such way:

```
std::time_t const now_c = std::time(0);
auto strTime = std::put_time(std::localtime(&now_c), "%F %T");
```

However, I need to use

```
#pragma warning(disable : 4996)
```

to be able to even compile it (Visual Studio would say: error C4996: 'localtime': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using localtime_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS.)

How do I get current date in an elegant, working, not deprecated, efficient, sensible and C++ way?

Comment: I recommend looking into this excellent [c++11 onwards date library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date).

Comment: perhaps the [std::tm](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/tm) could help you? I know you said localtime is deprecated, but it's c++11 compliant

Comment: `localtime`is not deprecated in any way, just considered "unsafe" by Microsoft. If you don't agree with that, just add `_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` to your project's macros.

Comment: #define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS is sensible

Comment: Okay, will use the define if it doesn't matter.

Comment: could you please accept an answer to close the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::localtime` isn't deprecated, merely called "unsafe" by microsoft compilers, apply this to avoid

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
```

Answer (score 1):

> How do I get current date in an elegant, working, not deprecated, efficient, sensible and C++ way?

Here is how you would do this using the [free, open-source C++11/14 library](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html) mentioned by [ArchbishopOfBanterbury](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5508296/archbishopofbanterbury) in the comments:

```
#include "tz.h"
#include <string>

int
main()
{
    auto const now = date::make_zoned(date::current_zone(),
                                      std::chrono::system_clock::now());
    auto strTime = date::format("%F %T", now);
}
```

This is thread safe, and uses the modern C++11/14 `<chrono>` library as its foundation.  This will output the time to the accuracy of `system_clock::time_point` (100ns on VS).  If you prefer to truncate it to seconds, that is accomplished like so:

```
using namespace std::chrono;
using namespace date;
auto const now = make_zoned(current_zone(), floor<seconds>(system_clock::now()));
auto strTime = format("%F %T", now);
```

If you wish to get the local time somewhere else, just enter the [IANA name](http://www.iana.org/time-zones) for that timezone in place of `current_zone()`:

```
auto const now = make_zoned("Europe/London", floor<seconds>(system_clock::now()));
```